# Erro ao Carregar Model no CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Olá,

Estou tentando carregar a model dentro do meu *controller* da seguinte forma:

```
$this->load->model("gerente");
```

Mas simplesmente tudo depois deste código não funciona, já tentei carregar passando *"Gerente"* ao invés de *"gerente"* mas a única diferença é que dessa forma aparece *"Erro 500"*.

Aqui está o código da Model que estou tentando chamar:

```
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
require_once 'usuario.php';

class Gerente extends Usuario {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
    }
}

/* End of file gerente.php  */
/* Location: ./application/models/gerente.php */
```

Usuario é uma classe que está chamando `CI_MODEL`.
E já estou carregando a *database* `$this->load->database();`

Comment: Carregou a database no autoload? `$this->load->database(); $this->load->model("gerente");` O que tem nesse *required*? Eu geralmente monto uma classe e a estendo.

Comment: Sim, carreguei a database no autoload.
Perdão, esqueci de comentar sobre o extend, estou utilizano CI_MODEL no arquivo usuario.php, e mesmo que eu chame somente $this->load->model('usuario'), não aparece nenhum erro, só que nada depois daquele código funciona, igual 'gerente'

Answer (score 1):

Seu arquivo gerente.php deve estender a classe `CI_Model` do CodeIgniter para então carregar o construtor pai dessa classe.

```
//gerente.php Model
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
    //require_once 'usuario.php';

    class Gerente extends CI_Model {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
        }
        //TODO here
    }

//home.php Controller
<?php if (!defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');     
    class Home extends CI_Controller {
        public function __construct() {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('gerente'); // ou no autoload do config.php ou em cada método.
        }
        //TODO here
    }
```

Comment: Perdão, esqueci de comentar sobre o extend, estou utilizano CI_MODEL no arquivo usuario.php, e mesmo que eu chame somente $this->load->model('usuario'), não aparece nenhum erro, só que nada depois daquele código funciona, igual 'gerente'

Comment: Inclua o error_reporting(E_ALL) no começo para mostrar warnings e erros das classes. Inclua alguns prints para debugar a execução do model, pois, em teoria, deveria funcionar!

Comment: Cara, muito curioso, estou utilizando a url /user/cadastrar para chamar a controller, adicionei um echo antes de chamar a model e um depois, o que ta antes imprime, mas o mais curioso é que abri a aba Network do navegador e está dando erro 500 para /user/

Comment: Deve ter algo faltando dentro do seu model usuarios.php ou tem algo a mais que finaliza a execução. Inclua os prints ao longo das funções ou no construtor. Onde não imprimir deverá acusar o erro!

Comment: Cara, valeu! Além de estar chamando $this->load->database() em vários lugares, o que provavelmente não é o correto, comentei minha função inserir na model usuário e funcionou corretamente, só falta eu averiguar o que estava fazendo de errado na função, mas isso é outra história... Valeu! hehe